# Как выполнить действие по свайпу, если знаешь имя класса?

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые специалисты. Скажите, возможно ли такое:

> Есть `css` класс `abcd`, в мобильном устройстве по нему делается
> свайп. Можно ли на этот свайп произвести *JS* действие, например
> `alert()`?

Возможно вопрос примитивный, но я что-то не могу нагуглить. Если не сложно, киньте ссылку, где можно прочесть.

Comment: почитайте про TouchEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать для этого *TouchEvent*. Подробнее тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("Good")[0].addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {           
console.log("Работает!")                    
event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="Good" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color:red;"></div>
```